# Center element with class

Tags: html, css, class, center

I have the follow problem, that the tripadviser element not center inside the div:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="center">
      <div id="TA_rated652" class="TA_rated">
         <ul id="aZ2UznGh" class="TA_links ztx26p">
            <li id="FyjgLOVkx" class="tmeRQwSrMol"><a href="http://www.tripadvisor.de/Attraction_Review-g293918-d1942956-Reviews-The_Dive_Academy-Koh_Samui_Surat_Thani_Province.html" class="center">The Dive Academy</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <script src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=rated&amp;uniq=652&amp;locationId=1942956&amp;lang=de"></script>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block05 .center { 
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:center;
 }
```

How I can center my tripadvisor element?

Answer (score 1):

By default, an element has a width of 100%, therefore you are unable to center it..

You can simply set a `width` on `.box` to fix this.

```
.box {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 170px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2DNQP/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see .block05 in your HTML.

To center a div within a div when using text-align is not an option, you can set an explicit width on the div and set margin:0 auto;

```
.element{
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This will center the element within the confines of it's container element.